# USB 2.0 1 to 4 port splitter not working

Tags: usb

This is the output of lsusb -v on ubuntu 12.04

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:2fb1 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0408 Quanta Computer, Inc.
  idProduct          0x2fb1 
  bcdDevice            9.01
  iManufacturer           3 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength         1457
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          2 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              250mA
    ** UNRECOGNIZED:  24 ff 42 49 53 54 00 01 05 02 10 00 00 00 00 00 01 05 d0 07 02 06 d0 07 03 07 d0 07 04 08 d0 07 05 09 d0 07
```

lsusb -v : http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7218456/

lspci -v : http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7218460/

Comment: Please add to your question the Ubuntu release you're using (12.04, 13.10), links to http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ of both `lspci` and `lsusb -vvv` full output.

Comment: @SylvainPineau Added.

Comment: One thing you could try is to boot with a 14.04 beta2 live CD and check if your hub is working correctly with a recent kernel.

Comment: @SylvainPineau I tried it on Linux Mint 16, Windows 7, Linux Mint KDE, does not work anywhere.. It runs the cooling fan but does not recognize pendrives,etc.

Comment: @SahilSareen: Its time to replace your USB Hub with a new one, hope it is still in warranty period.. ;)

Comment: @SauravKumar But its a new one, even after getting it replaced twice it does not work..

Comment: @SahilSareen Does it work on a different computer?

Comment: @Sparhawk nopes.. Does not work anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hub doesn't work on multiple computers and operating systems, that suggests that the computer themselves are not to blame. It's likely that the USB hub is broken.

If you've had the hub replaced multiple times, then it's probably a faulty batch, or poorly-made model.

I'd recommend returning it as faulty, and buying a different model, and probably a different brand.

==EDIT==

In general, you don't need drivers for USB hubs. Almost all hubs will work out-of-the-box. In addition, I agree that Linux sometimes has driver issues with other hardware, but again, if it's not working in Windows, this is more evidence that this is not the case.

Comment: Do I need any extra drivers for it?

Comment: @SahilSareen I edited the answer in response.

Comment: However I got this: http://download.cnet.com/Generic-USB-Hub/3000-18493_4-55788.html

Comment: @SahilSareen Interesting. I wonder if that is for "advanced" features. I can't imagine how it's necessary for base functionality. Also, I would have thought that Windows would have automatically installed this, if it were necessary. Since it still didn't work in Windows, that also suggests to me that the lack of drivers are not to blame.